# Disabling user/app credential deployment in App Service Plan

Tags: azure, kudu, azure-app-service-plans

Is it possible to disable user-level credential deployment in a particular App Service Plan?

In a development environment deploying directly to the AppService is fine, however  a production environment should require more gates e.g. via a release pipeline.

User-level credentials are shared across an entire azure account, is it possible to disable them for production?

The portal indicates the ability to disable ftp, but it doesn't suggest this covers deployments in general.

Is it possible to disable app-level credentials as well? I'm wary of it's audit-ability not being tied to an individual user.

EDIT:

The release pipeline is currently using the MSDeploy extension within an ARM template. For this app we're currently not using deployment slots, but that's a good point we would use them for other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no at this moment.  As long as the user is a contributor to the site, he/she will be able to browse to the relevant SCM site (meaning making changes/deployment).   Similarly, for app-level cred.   Could you clarify what type of cred is being used to do release pipeline?   Does it mean deploy to slot and swap is the only mean of deployment?